# how to fit docker compose to swarm mode

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm building a selenium grid that could hold multiple browsers for running automation script, after some time I had find the way to deploy into swarm mode.

```
version: '3'
networks:
  private:
    driver: overlay
services:
  selenium_hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
    networks:
      - private

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
    volumes:
      - /dev/urandom:/dev/random
    depends_on:
      - selenium_hub
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium_hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
      - NODE_MAX_SESSION=1
    entrypoint: bash -c 'SE_OPTS="-host $$HOSTNAME -port 5555" /opt/bin/entry_point.sh'
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    networks:
      - private

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    volumes:
      - /dev/urandom:/dev/random
    depends_on:
      - selenium_hub
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium_hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
      - NODE_MAX_SESSION=1
    entrypoint: bash -c 'SE_OPTS="-host $$HOSTNAME -port 5556" /opt/bin/entry_point.sh'
    ports:
      - 5556:5556
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    networks:
      - private
```

My swarm now can run web automation scripts with scale, but me issue is to improve me grid to hold android emulators and real devices.
In order to implement me required I found nice example that allow me to deploy selenium grid with android emulators, but I can't convert my YAML file to fit swarm mode.

I want to know what I did wrong and what should be the keys difference between docker-compose command to docker stack deploy.

The data I want to add is:

```
  real_device:
    image: appium/appium
    depends_on:
      - selenium_hub
    network_mode: "service:selenium_hub"
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb
      - ~/.android:/root/.android
      - $PWD/example/sample_apk:/root/tmp
    environment:
      - CONNECT_TO_GRID=true
      - SELENIUM_HOST=selenium_hub
      # Enable it for msite testing
      #- BROWSER_NAME=chrome

  # Docker-Android for Android application testing
  nexus_7.1.1:
    image: budtmo/docker-android-x86-7.1.1
    privileged: true
    # Increase scale number if needed
    scale: 1
    depends_on:
      - selenium_hub
      - real_device
    ports:
      - 6080
    # Change path of apk that you want to test. I use sample_apk that I provide in folder "example"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/example/sample_apk:/root/tmp/sample_apk
      - ./video-nexus_7.1.1:/tmp/video
    environment:
      - DEVICE=Nexus 5
      - CONNECT_TO_GRID=true
      - APPIUM=true
      - SELENIUM_HOST=selenium_hub
      - AUTO_RECORD=true

  # Docker-Android for mobile website testing with chrome browser
  # Chrome browser exists only for version 7.0 and 7.1.1
  samsung_galaxy_web_7.1.1:
    image: budtmo/docker-android-x86-8.1
    privileged: true
    # Increase scale number if needed
    scale: 1
    depends_on: 
      - selenium_hub
      - real_device
    ports:
      - 6080
    volumes:
      - ./video-samsung_7.1.1:/tmp/video
    environment:
      - DEVICE=Samsung Galaxy S6
      - CONNECT_TO_GRID=true
      - APPIUM=true
      - SELENIUM_HOST=selenium_hub
      - MOBILE_WEB_TEST=true
      - AUTO_RECORD=true

  # Docker-Android for mobile website testing with default browser
  # Default browser exists only for version 5.0.1, 5.1.1 and 6.0
  samsung_galaxy_web_5.1.1:
    image: budtmo/docker-android-x86-5.1.1
    privileged: true
    # Increase scale number if needed
    scale: 1
    depends_on:
      - selenium_hub
      - real_device
    ports:
      - 6080
    volumes:
      - ./video-samsung_5.1.1:/tmp/video
    environment:
      - DEVICE=Samsung Galaxy S6
      - CONNECT_TO_GRID=true
      - APPIUM=true
      - SELENIUM_HOST=selenium_hub
      - MOBILE_WEB_TEST=true
      - AUTO_RECORD=true
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: nexus_7.1.1 Additional property nexus_7.1.1 is not allowed

Answer (score 1):

Privileged containers are not currently supported by swarm mode. You can follow Docker's progress implanting the feature here: https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1030

As a hacky workaround, I've seen some users run a docker client container as a service, mounting the docker socket, and running `docker run --privileged --rm ...` as the command in that service.

An example of the hacky workaround would look like:

```
version: '3.5'
networks:
  private:
    name: selenium_private
    attachable: true
services:
  real_device:
    image: docker
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command:
    - docker
    - run
    - --rm
    - --privileged
    - -v
    - /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb
    - -v
    - /path/to/.android:/root/.android
    - -v
    - /path/to/example/sample_apk:/root/tmp
    - -e
    - CONNECT_TO_GRID=true
    - -e
    - SELENIUM_HOST=selenium_hub
    - --net
    - selenium_private
    - appium/appium
```

The one piece I didn't include there is the network. It looks like selenium wants everything running in a single network namespace, which will be a bit difficult to implement. You can create a single dummy container with a known name outside of swarm mode and attach everything to that container name's network namespace. If you can get it to work over the overlay networking to communicate between services (the way most microservices work), then I updated the definition of the private network to be attachable and gave it a name (which required the 3.5 compose version).